# Datagrid.RowEditEnding doesn't return the update value

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new in C# WPF and is doing some very basic test on DataGrid. I can bind the data to the DataGrid but after I amend the row, I can received only old data. Can someone tell me what's wrong in my code? Here is my code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="abc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dgEmployee" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  RowEditEnding="OnRowEditEnding">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding EmpNo}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding EmpName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding Salary,
                    StringFormat='#,##0.00'}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace abc
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        EmployeeList emp = new EmployeeList();


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgEmployee.ItemsSource = emp;
        }

        private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
        {
            var _emp = e.Row.Item as Employee;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("updated record:\n{0}\n{1}\n{2}",
            _emp.EmpNo, _emp.EmpName, _emp.Salary));
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Employee class:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace abc
{
    public class Employee
    {
        private int _empNo;
        private string _empName;
        private decimal _salary;

        public Employee(int Id, string Name, decimal wage)
        {
            this._empNo = Id;
            this._empName = Name;
            this._salary = wage;
        }

        public int EmpNo { get { return _empNo; } set { _empNo = value; } }
        public string EmpName { get { return _empName; } set { _empName = value; } }
        public decimal Salary { get { return _salary; } set { _salary = value; } }
    }

    public class EmployeeList : ObservableCollection<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeList()
            : base()
        {
            Add(new Employee(1, "Bart Simpson", (decimal)10));
            Add(new Employee(2, "Homer Simpson", (decimal)500));
            Add(new Employee(3, "Maggie Simpson", (decimal)200));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what ammend means but maybe you need to implement propertychanged?

Comment: +1 Great first question with lots of code :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to change your WPF bindings to force an update back to your `Employee` class every time the property is changed. At the moment, by default, it only updates when the focus is lost which happens after the OnRowEditEnding event:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding EmpNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: I really wish I found this earlier

Comment: I added `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, but I'm still not getting the new value.?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
update a static list of rows to be changed
use another event to update the row(s) after the roweditending event

```
   private void datagrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        rows2change.Add(e.Row.GetIndex());
    }

    private void datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rows2change.Count > 0)
        {
            saveMyData(rows2change[0]);
            rows2change.Remove(rows2change[0]);
        }
    }
```