# How to update Datagrid with OleDB?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, oledb

I use the following code to fill my datagrid dgFolien:

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "SELECT Hersteller,Serie,Farbe,[EK-Preis] FROM Folien";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

OleDbDataAdapter dataAdp = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Folien");
dataAdp.Fill(dt);
dgFolien.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
dataAdp.Update(dt);

connection.Close();
```

Now my problem: The user should just doubleclick into a cell, edit the value, leave the cell and the table should be updated in my database.

How can I handle this?

I found that it can work with RowEditEnding, but I have no idea about the code for updating my database.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to handle the event something like this:

```
private void dgFolien_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataContext as DataRowView;
    if (drv != null)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("yourConnectionString..."))
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var1", drv["Hersteller"].ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var2", drv["Serie"].ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var3", drv["Farbe"].ToString()));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@var4", drv["EK-Preis"].ToString()));


            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Folien SET Hersteller=@var1, Serie=@var2, Farbe=@var3 WHERE [EK-Preis] = @var4";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the bindings to `PropertyChanged` in the XAML markup for the column values to be set immediately: [Datagrid.RowEditEnding doesn't return the update value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236149/datagrid-roweditending-doesnt-return-the-update-value)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgFolien" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Height="268" Margin="10,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="489" ColumnWidth="*" RowEditEnding="dgFolien_RowEditEnding">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hersteller" Binding="{Binding Hersteller, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serie" Binding="{Binding Serie, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Farbe" Binding="{Binding Farbe, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="EK-Preis" Binding="{Binding EK-Preis, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Used this code and added Parameter var5, but changes dont update in database

                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Folien SET Hersteller=@var1, Serie=@var2, Farbe=@var3, [EK-Preis]=@var4 WHERE FolienID = @var5";

Comment: Yes, no problems with executing. Maybe problems with the connection string?
I used "using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connection.ConnectionString))"
and "connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database Calculator.mdb;
            Persist Security Info=False;";"
ConnectionString is working with showing table and so on.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or what happens?

Comment: Nothing happens. I edit a cell in my DataGrid, then I close the application or go to another view/page. Then I go back to my DataGrid and the cell I edited before hasnt changed.

Comment: See my edit regarding the UpdateSourceTrigger property.

Comment: Well, I didnt used the UpdateSourceTrigger property. Here's my XAML Markup for my datagrid:
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgFolien" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="268" Margin="10,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="489" ColumnWidth="*" RowEditEnding="dgFolien_RowEditEnding"/>
What to change?

Comment: You should define each column explicitly for this to work. See my edit.

Comment: YES! It's working now. 
Please dont forget to set the AutoGenerateColumns="True" as false!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Another question: How can I handle with integer or double values?
For Example EK-Preis is a double value. In my DataGrid I cant type in a comma or a dot. Any idea?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask questions in the comments field.

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same code. You should use SQL command UPDATE in RowEditEnding

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: this line             command.CommandText = "SELECT Hersteller,Serie,Farbe,[EK-Preis] FROM Folien";
change to UPDATE command, not SELECT

Comment: So i just write:
   `code`   try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Update;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();}

Comment: oh my fault, now i Know what u mean! TY!

Comment: Do i need something like  "command.CommandText = "UPDATE Folien SET ..." or is it possible to do it like "command.CommandText = "UPDATE Folien";" ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible ;)

Comment: Is it still command.ExecuteNonQuery() ? And just "UPDATE Table" ?

Comment: Same problem like in the other comment:  
Nothing happens. I edit a cell in my DataGrid, then I close the application or go to another view/page. Then I go back to my DataGrid and the cell I edited before hasnt changed.